# yaml - Print key and value, if value meets consitions

Tags: yaml, yq

Given the following yaml:

```yaml
charts:
  # repository with Helm charts for creation namespaces
  path: ns
  pathMonitoringPrometheus: prom

namespaces:
  first:
    description: "Description of first"
    enabled: false
    branch: master
    bootstrapChart: bootstrap
    syncAccessGroups: []
    namespace:
      role: k8s-role-of-first
      istio: disabled
      public: view
    sources: []

  second:
    description: "Description of second"
    enabled: false
    branch: HEAD
    bootstrapChart: bootstrap
    namespace:
      role: k8s-role-of-second
      istio: 1-13-2
      labels:
        label: second
    sources:
      - http://url.of.second
```

How could we get a list of `namespaces` and their `istio` value if it is different to "disabled".

We are trying to use "yq" tool, but I guess any approach would be ok, although "yq" would be a preferred approach.

```
second, 1-13-2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) you can base your filter on `jq`.

- `to_entries` splits up the object into an array of key-value pairs
- `select` selects those items matching your criteria
- [String interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C%28foo%29) in combination with the `-r` option puts together your desired output

```sh
yq -r '
  .namespaces
  | to_entries[]
  | select(.value.namespace.istio != "disabled")
  | "\(.key), \(.value.namespace.istio)"
'
```

```
second, 1-13-2
```

---

Using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) the filter is quite similar.

- `to_entries[]` has to be split up `to_entries | .[]`
- String interpolation is replaced using `join` and an array

```sh
yq '
  .namespaces
  | to_entries | .[]
  | select(.value.namespace.istio != "disabled")
  | [.key, .value.namespace.istio] | join(", ")
'
```

```
second, 1-13-2
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much. I did saw docs with the "-r" option but my yq did not had that so I moved forward with the options I had. Now I know why I did not had the option :)

Comment: @SebastiánGreco Added a variant using mikefarah/yq.

Answer (score 1):

this will do:

```sh
cat  /path/tp/your.yaml |yq -r  '.namespaces | to_entries[] | "\(.key)  \(.value.namespace.istio)"'`
```

will result:

```
first  disabled
second  1-13-2
```